# Postgres Join based on Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, levenshtein-distance, stringdist

I am trying to make use of the levenshtein distance in my join condition.

Since the sqlalchemy doesn't provide the implementation within func module, I set the method stringdist.rdlevenshtein_norm to func.rdlevenshtein_norm and used it in my sqlalchemy join, like below.

```
import stringdist
import sqlalchemy as sa

sa.func.rdlevenshtein_norm = stringdist.rdlevenshtein_norm

on_cond = [func.rdlevenshtein_norm(rel_a[str_col_a].column, rel_b[str_col_b].column) < 0.2]

sa.join(rel_a.table, rel_b.table, sa.and_(*on_cond),
                         isouter=outer, full=full)
```

But the function `stringdist.rdlevenshtein_norm` expects 2 strings as input and hence not working well with sqlalchemy to compare all the values in the 2 joining columns.

> So the error I am getting for on_cond is , **TypeError('argument 1 must be str, not
>   Column',)**

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make sqlalchemy use this function while performing join operation?

Comment: can't I create a generic method (sa.func.rdlevenshtein_norm) to implement the rdlevenshtein_norm?

Comment: No it doesn't..

Comment: Update: 
I created a generic function

`class rdlevenshtein_norm(GenericFunction):
    type = stringdist.rdlevenshtein_norm`

Then called it as,

`func.rdlevenshtein_norm(rel_a[str_col_a].column, rel_b[str_col_b].column)`

This gives me an error

`TypeError('function takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)',) `